How to add additional documents to a Docusign Composite Template that has tabs?
I have a server template that has two documents, two recipients and two custom tabs placed on top of the first page of the first document.
My business requirements is to add a supplement document at the end of the documents provided by the server template. How do you accomplish that? I have literally tried every possible JSON combination. Here is my latest failed attempt:
{
    "emailSubject": "Electronic Signature Request",
    "emailBlurb": "Hi! an electronic signature request has been sent your way!",
    "status": "created",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "hello-39ba-40a1-975d-world"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "signer1@domain.com",
                                "name": "Signer One",
                                "roleName": "Contact",
                                "tabs": {}
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "signer2@domain.com",
                                "name": "Signer Two",
                                "roleName": "Signer 2",
                                "tabs": {}
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "signer_not_in_template@domain.com",
                                "name": "Amy Anderson",
                                "roleName": "Signer 3",
                                "recipientId": 3,
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "Doc Version",
                                            "value": "July FDD",
                                            "customTabId": "foo-foo-406d-814f-cc145e24634e"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "Recipient label",
                                            "value": "Anderson",
                                            "customTabId": "foo-foo-43c9-9759-28b1158dcb42"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "document": {
                "documentId": 1,
                "name": "supplement-doc.pdf",
                "documentBase64": "JVBERi0..."
            }
        }
    ]
}

The error thrown is:
{
    "errorCode": "TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT",
    "message": "The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 66891084 which is not present."
}

There are errors everywhere... After two days I am literally pulling out my hair...

The embedded signing example tool enables you to include supplemental documents. Use the Classic Signing Tab and HTML Regular Responsive doc to see how a composite template is used. Here's a link with those optins
Use the tool's Start Logging control (top navigation bar) to see the API calls being made, including the details of the Composite Templates.
Including a supplemental document with a composite template
The supplemental document is included as a separate CompositeTemplate item in the array of Composite Templates. The level of signer acceptance of the supplemental doc is set via the signerMustAcknowledge property:

no_interaction -- No recipient action is required.
view -- The recipient is required to view the document.
accept -- The recipient is required to accept the document by selecting accept during signing, but is not required to view the document.
view_accept -- The recipient is required to view and accept the document.

There's a fifth level of acknowledgement, read to the end and accept. Additional tabs must be added to the envelope to provide this UX. See the test tool for an example or ask a new question
Working example of using a template for the main doc and adding a supplemental doc:
{
    "useDisclosure": true,
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "1",
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "b0bd1283-079d-4fa5-8588-xxxxxxxx"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "clientUserId": 1000, # Enables embedded
                                                      # signing
                                "email": "larry@example.com",
                                "name": "Larry Kluger",
                                "roleName": "signer",
                                "recipientId": "1"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "compositeTemplateId": "11",
            "document": {
                "name": "Terms and Conditions 1.pdf",
                "display": "modal",
                "fileExtension": "pdf",
                "documentId": "1",
                "signerMustAcknowledge": "view_accept",
                "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iago8PC...."
            },
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1" # this "null" inline template is needed
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}



Your document looks like it is sitting outside the compositeTemplate array. I adjusted your request to include the document inside the compositeTemplate array and added recipientIds to the first and second recipient. It should work now, with a valid base64
    {
    "emailSubject": "Electronic Signature Request",
    "emailBlurb": "Hi! an electronic signature request has been sent your way!",
    "status": "created",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "{{templateId}}"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "signer1@domain.com",
                                "name": "Signer One",
                                "roleName": "Contact",
                                "recipientId":"1",
                                "tabs": {}
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "signer2@domain.com",
                                "name": "Signer Two",
                                "roleName": "Signer 2",
                                "recipientId":"2",
                                "tabs": {}
                            },
                            {
                                "email": "signer_not_in_template@domain.com",
                                "name": "Amy Anderson",
                                "roleName": "Signer 3",
                                "recipientId": 3,
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "Doc Version",
                                            "value": "July FDD",
                                            "customTabId": "foo-foo-406d-814f-cc145e24634e"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "tabLabel": "Recipient label",
                                            "value": "Anderson",
                                            "customTabId": "foo-foo-43c9-9759-28b1158dcb42"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": 1,
                "name": "supplement-doc.pdf",
                "documentBase64": "JVBERi0..."
            }
        }
    ]
}


 


This is not correct. See my answer.
